# Simulate Multibody System with Partial Trajectory

Tags: drake

In Python Drake, I have a `MultibodyPlant` system that I have defined from a URDF. I am working on a trajectory optimization that involves hand-calculated contact dynamics, and I want to test out the trajectory that I calculated using the built-in simulator in Drake. I'm currently visualizing the entire calculated trajectory using `MultibodyPositionToGeometryPose` with `TrajectorySource` on a complete numpy array of all bodies in my system.

However, I want to test out my trajectory with the system dynamics handled instead by Drake. Is there a way to pass in a trajectory for some of the positions (i.e. joints connected to some of the links), and let the Drake simulation calculate the rest of them? I'd like to do this before attempting to implement a stabilized LQR controller to evaluate just the accuracy of my hand-calculated contact dynamics.

Answer (score 0):

That feature is coming soon in the newest contact solver in Drake (https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/16738), but as of today, you could do this using a [PidController](https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/classdrake_1_1systems_1_1controllers_1_1_pid_controller.html) with the `state_projection` matrix to select the subset of joints you would want to command.  Those joints will need to have actuators on them.